# optimizing simple select query in oracle

Tags: oracle, optimization

I am trying to optimize the following query:

```
 SELECT   tickstime AS time,
          quantity1 AS turnover
    FROM   cockpit_test.ticks
   WHERE   date_id BETWEEN 20111104 AND 20111109 
     AND   mdc_id IN (297613)
ORDER BY   time;
```

It is pretty simple but it takes about 60-90 seconds to run. **cockpit_test.TICKS** table contains more than 100M of rows. It also has an index by **MDC_ID** and **DATE_ID** columns.

EXPLAIN PLAN gives the following output

```
"-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
"| Id  | Operation                    | Name           | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |"
"-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
"|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                | 26905 |   604K|       | 11783   (1)| 00:02:22 |"
"|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY               |                | 26905 |   604K|   968K| 11783   (1)| 00:02:22 |"
"|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TICKS          | 26905 |   604K|       | 11596   (1)| 00:02:20 |"
"|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | TICKS_MDC_DATE | 26905 |       |       |    89   (0)| 00:00:02 |"
"-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
" "
"Predicate Information (identified by operation id):"
"---------------------------------------------------"
" "
"   3 - access(""MDC_ID""=297613 AND ""DATE_ID"">=20111104 AND ""DATE_ID""<=20111109)"
```

So I am not completely sure what all that means, but it seems that index is being hit and most time is being consumed by accessing rows by index rowid.

Are there any ways to make this query run faster?

**UPD**

Here is the table definition:

```
Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
DATE_ID                                   NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
MDC_ID                                    NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
TICKSTIME                                 NOT NULL DATE
STATE                                     NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
VALUE1                                    NOT NULL FLOAT(126)
VALUE2                                             FLOAT(126)
VOLUME1                                            FLOAT(126)
VOLUME2                                            FLOAT(126)
QUANTITY1                                          NUMBER(38)
QUANTITY2                                          NUMBER(38)
```

There are 3 indexes on the table:

- Index on MDC_ID
- Compound index on DATE_ID, MDC_ID, TICKSTIME
- Compound index on DATE_ID, MDC_ID

Comment: can you show your table definition? keys, indexes

Comment: "order by time", or should that be "order by tickstime"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check that this explain plan has accurate estimations of the cardinalities. It's quite typical for the cardinality to poorly estimated when multiple predicates are supplied, and the execution time seems very high for such a small query and estimated sort size (unless you have grossly underpowered storage infrastructure, which again is pretty typical).

Given the duration of the query I'd make sure that the estimate is accurate by invoking dynamic sampling ...

```
SELECT
  /*+ dynamic_sampling(4) */
  tickstime AS time,
  quantity1 AS turnover
FROM
  cockpit_test.ticks
WHERE
  date_id BETWEEN 20111104 AND 20111109 and
  mdc_id IN (297613)
ORDER BY
 tickstime;
```

If it turns out that the estimated temp space is smaller than realtiy (and you can check that by querying V$SQL_WORKAREA_ACTIVE) then you might have to tweak the memory settings for the session to switch to automatic memory management and increase the sort area size.

Comment: Nothing else we could do except the database tuning so marking this answer as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In general, Oracle can't combine two separate indexes (unless they're bitmap indexes and not "ordinary" btree indexes).

What is the `mdc_id` column? If there are many distinct values for it, you could create a compound index on `mdc_id, date_id`.

In theory, Oracle can use an index to return sorted data. In this case your index should be on `mdc_id, date_id, time`.

Why aren't you using date datatypes for your date columns? For this particular query it probably won't make much difference, but in general Oracle will much better be able to determine the distribution of data if you use correct datatypes.

Comment: I like the three-column index idea, but because the date_id predicate is based on a range I think it is unlikely to work as the index order is different to the order requested -- (20111104,1234) would appear before (20111107,0932). It would work for single date_id values though, which could be useful.

Comment: TICKS_MDC_DATE index is an compound index on mdc_id, date_id. A compound index on date_id, mdc_id, time also exists.

Regarding datatypes all I can say is that we are using a legacy database with a lot of weird things and this is something we have to adapt to :(